# How to check if username exists in EditText(Text Changed Listener) by using Firebase.?

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-edittext

I tried many ways.But nothing works.can you help me please.my Firebase Structure is [I want to check username exists or not from searching in Usernames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVjzN.png)

It works By clicking Submit button.But,I want to implements it's on EditText with automatic searching on text changed.How can i do it.?
Advanced thanks

```
        usrnm.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, 
    int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue().equals(usrname)){
                   usrnm.setError("Username Unavailable");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: are u getting only one value ?? i dont think so ....

Comment: No.i did n't get anything.i tried it with toast.that works...

Comment: I did n't get any value.But.,I checked it with toast.it works..

Comment: what did u toasted? dataSnapshot.getValue() ?

Comment: No.i checked editText only...i checked is it working or not.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use textwatcher and inside three method before after onchange text and your firebase datasnapshot to get data and compare with edittext value any query comment here.

Comment: Please Check my edited question now.Is there any problem?

Answer (score 0):

use TextChangeListner in EditText.
for Eg...

```
EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eg);
username.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            //here when user enter our username in EditText (While entering)
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please Check my edited question now.Is there any problem?

Answer (score 0):

you may get some error because I wrote this from my memory but u should do it like this.

```
       ArrayList<String> allUserName = new ArrayList();
       mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             allUserName =(ArrayList<String>) 
              dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
    username.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, 
     int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int 
 i2) {
        if (allUserName.contains(usrname)){
               usrnm.setError("Username Unavailable");
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    }
});
```